# Firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword() returning HTTP POST error failure along with error object

Tags: angular, firebase, error-handling, http-post, firebase-authentication

While working with Angular5 with firebase as the database, I'm trying to create a new user from `createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)`.

But when I'm entering an already existing email (for testing), the function is returning HTTP POST error along (not expected) with an error-object (expected).

I tried catching the error with `.catch()` but the HTTP POST error is still printing to console along with the firebase URL with my API key.

Here's my code in AuthService typescript class:

```
  signupUser(username: string, password: string) {
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(username, password)
      .catch(function(err) {
        const errorCode = err.code;
        const errorMsg = err.message;
        console.log('Error code: ', errorCode);
        console.log('Error Message: ', errorMsg);
        console.log('Error: ', err);
      });
  }
```

Here's where the above code is being called:

```
  onSignup(form: NgForm) {
    const username: string = form.value.username;
    const password: string = form.value.password;
    try {
      this.authService.signupUser(username, password);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('try-catch called ');
    }
  }
```

Here's what's getting displayed on the console:

[image: See this]

Kindly suggest what I'm doing wrong here as I don't want that HTTP POST message printing to the console showing my API_KEY.

Also [here is a git issue](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/issues/166) regarding the same.

Comment: Isn't the error there? `Error code: auth/email-already-in-use` and `Error Message: The email address is already in use by another account.` Maybe try deleting the user who has registered the same email address multiple times?

Comment: Yes the errors are showing but what I want to know is how to catch that `HTTP POST 400 error` which is showing above those errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Authentication SDK communicates with its backend through HTTP requests. Your browser's JavaScript console simply shows the HTTP response code that the Firebase Authentication server sends back to the client.

There is no way to suppress this message through an API. If you don't want to see this, you can try turning off error logging in your JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

You need an if statement (or case if you want catch multiple things) after the call to the createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword().
in that if stmt, check for the returned error code matching "auth/email-already-in-use
" then reset the error message to the message you want and display it to your users.

```
    firebase.auth().createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(
  email, password).catch(function(error) {
      // Handle Errors here.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      if (errorCode == 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
        console.log('auth/email-already-in-use.');
      } else {
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
      console.log(error);
    });
```

See the docs and returned error codes for this method:
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#createUserWithEmailAndPassword

Also note, that if your objective is to hide the API-key, anybody with http filter can observe it even after you handle the error because the http call to firebase is fired & returned to your app!

Comment: What i wanted to catch is the `HTTP POST's 400 error` itself which as explained by `Frank van Puffelen` is not possible.